# Data streamed from Kafka to Postgres and missing seconds later

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to save data from local Kafka instance to local Postgres with Spark Streaming. I have configured all connections and parameters, and data actually gets to the database. However, it is there only for a couple of seconds. After that, the table simply becomes empty. If I stop the app as soon there is some data in Postgres, data persists, so I suppose I have missed some parameter for streaming in Spark or something in Kafka configuration files. The code is in Java, not Scala, so there is dataset instead of DataFrame.

I tried setting `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` to true, but this has nothing with context. When I run count on database with complete data set streaming in the background, there is always about 1700 records, which means there might be some parameter for batch size.

```
censusRecordJavaDStream.map(e -> {
    Row row = RowFactory.create(e.getAllValues());
    return row;
}).foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    Dataset<Row> censusDataSet = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, CensusRecord.getStructType());

    censusDataSet
            .write()
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:postgres", "census.census", connectionProperties);
});
```

My goal is to stream data from Kafka and save it to Postgre. Each record has unique ID, which is used as a key in Kafka, so there should be no conflicts regarding primary key or double entries. For current testing purposes, I am using small subset of about 100 records; complete dataset is over 300MB.

Comment: Instead `SaveMode.Overwrite`, try to use `SaveMode.Append`

Comment: This behaviour could be due to empty RDDs that are `SaveMode.Overwrite`'ing whatever content the table has got so far. You should check whether `rdd` is empty (`isEmpty`) and go ahead only when it's not.

Comment: Why don't you use [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)?

Comment: I have tried with ``Append`` mode, and it works as expected, thank you.

Comment: But I am curious - shouldn't Overwrite mode affect only records with identical ID's? For example, if there is a record with ID 333 in first batch, and then comes second batch with 333 record included (which has some change in other columns), I assumed that Overwrite mode was intended to overwrite only this duplicate record, and effectively leave you with updated data.